# Deploying change sets into production

Tags: change-set

When deploying change sets from Sand box to Production what happens to changes made to the production directly. For an example if a new field is added to a custom object in the production org, then a validation rule is added to the same object in the sand box and implemented into production via change set.

What happens to the new field added to the production org before?

Comment: VR deploys as independent changeSet Item and won't affect the newly-added-directly-into PROD custom field.

Answer (score 3):

The only time metadata components are overridden is when you have modified an existing component and you are deploying that component.

In your example, the field you created in production will be unaffected.

To illustrate the opposite effect, suppose you have a formula field you created in production.  In your sandbox, you have modified the formula for that field. When you deploy that field, the formula will be overridden with whatever was in the sandbox.

This concept can get very detailed with understanding what exactly constitutes a metadata component. For example, based on the fact that you asked this question, I assume you consider the object itself to be the component and therefore deploying a validation rule tied to that object will overwrite changes made. Salesforce, however, treats each individual field, validation rule, object, list view, etc as individual metadata components.

I hope this helps you understand!